# SQL/PHP and Tables - Making a Column with Text into URL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a column in a DB that populates a list within a table of the top gaining athletes on my fantasy sports website, on the website I would like to be able to have "Jamal Charles" be a url and have it linked to the internal webpage for Jamaal that was already created. below the table I have the function that is calling the "companyname" - companyname is actually the athletes name.

How would I make the "companyname" a link to its own page in this table? Would i make another function that calls the url instead? Make another column that accepts urls and call that? I hear that sometimes the database will only echo the url text and not make it a link. Is any of the possible?

Please let me know if you need more code. Thanks in advance everyone!

Top Gaining Athletes Today
1.  Jamaal Charles  0.54 %
2.  Kyle Rudolph    0.50 %
3.  A.J. Green  0.48 %
4.  Michael Bush    0.48 %
5.  Jared Cook  0.47 %
6.  Christian Ponder    0.45 %
7.  Alfred Morris   0.45 %
8.  Nate Washington 0.44 %
9.  Ryan Succop 0.44 %
10. DeMarco Murray  0.43 %

```
function getTopAthletes($connection){
$i=1;
$query = "SELECT b. companyname, (a.currentprice - a.open)/a.open as performance FROM jm_market a, jm_stocks b WHERE a.symbol = b.symbol AND active = 'Y' ORDER BY performance desc LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($query,$connection) or die('Problem with obtaining top PLAYERS: ' . $query); 
$output = "<table class='tab1 bborder' cellspacing='0'>";
$output.= "<th colspan='4'>Top Gaining Athletes Today</th>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  // Shorten really long names
  if (strlen($row['companyname']) > 20) {
     $short = split (' ', $row['companyname']);
     $row['companyname'] = substr( $short[0],0,1 ) . ". ";
     unset($short[0]);
     foreach ($short as $n) {
        $row['companyname'] .= $n . " ";
     } 
     $row['companyname'] = rtrim($row['companyname']);         
  }

    $output .="<tr ><td width='20px'><strong>" . $i.".</strong></td>";
    $output .="<td ><strong>" . $row['companyname']."</strong></td>";
    $output .="<td><strong>" . number_format(($row['performance']) * 100,2)." %</strong></td></tr>";
    $i++;

}
$output .= "</table>";
return $output;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$output .="<td ><strong><a href='users.php?username=" . $row['companyname']."'>". $row['companyname']."</a></strong></td>";
```

That should give you

```
<a href='users.php?username=John'>John</a>
```